# Turbulent boundary layer: viscous sublayer definition

Tags: boundary-conditions, viscosity, turbulence

I have seen different definitions of the viscous sublayer within a turbulent boundary layer, through my searches. Ones say that the viscous sublayer area is for $y \leq 10 * \delta_v$  where $\delta_v$ is the thickness of the viscous sublayer... which is strange because as others say and which seems more natural, the viscous sublayer exists for $y \leq \delta_v$.

Why do both definitions exist, and what is the meaning of the first one? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you perhaps referring to the laminar sublayer within a turbulent boundary layer?

Comment: Humm I think. And it is called the viscous sublayer.

Comment: Perhaps you provide a reference or a more detailed quotation?